# Will US CBP deny me entry because I broke a US lease in 2001?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens

I was in America in 2001 but broke my lease on the apartment I was staying when I was leaving. I have been invited to a wedding; will I be allowed in? I am taking my wife and kids but am scared I will not be allowed back in because of this or even get arrested. I am from the UK.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the CBP knows you've broken your lease.  In any event, if there is a judgment against you it will authorize a bailiff or the like to seize some assets in satisfaction of the judgment.  You would not be subject to arrest.  Since you presumably have no assets in the US, since they would have been seized already if you did, so you should be fine.

Comment: By "breaking my lease" do you mean that you didn't fulfill a contract you signed? Are you aware if the other parties of the contract attempted to take any action against you? In what state of the US was this?

Comment: @OP: it would be awesome if you could restructure your question a bit so that there are more commas and dots in particular after a sentence ends a dot is really helpful for many readers to read your post correctly as different writers tend to structure their posts in different ways so that without the dots they do not have the guidance to read your question correctly and quickly so please take the time to update your question accordingly many thanks

Comment: @CMaster in some US states, at least, if not most or all, residential leases are not controlled by general contract law.

Answer (score 4):

So you moved out early **14 years ago** and are concerned that you are on the watch list? Highly unlikely.

Unless you made a complete mess of the place requiring a complete rebuild, your previous landlord did little more than not return your deposit and put a "for rent" sign in the window. This stuff happens every week, and it is simply not worth the building owner's time to make a case over it. Rental property is civil, not criminal, so the police aren't getting involved either. After 14 years any statute of limitations will have run out too.

If you moved abruptly for serious criminal reasons (drug manufacture, dead bodies in the storage room etc.) you might be in trouble, but in that case someone would have filed for an international warrant a long time ago.

Comment: One exception to this is if you where renting in Arkansas where some aspects of lease law are treated as criminal and not civil law, though it seems this primarily concerns evictions (failure to vacate).